# embedding product of symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can $S_3 \times S_3$ be embedded into $A_6$? I know that the answer is no, but should I look if there is no $36$ elements subgroup in $A_6$ or is there a simpler way?

Comment: There are no elements of order $6$ in $A_6$.

Comment: Can you say how does it contradict?